The error when using ReceiveAsync and SendAsync to transmit text
I'm writing a server for creating an online chat in a WindowsFormsApp and encountered an error in ReceiveAsync and SendAsync. How can I fix it?
The issues start with trying to pass an argument into ReceiveAsync and SendAsync, resulting in an error about invalid arguments.
Server.cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class HostInformationFetcherServer
{
    public async Task<IPHostEntry> GetHostEntryAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();


            IPHostEntry ipEntry = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(hostName);

            IPAddress ip = ipEntry.AddressList[0];

            //connects the server socket to client socket
            IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, 1234);

            Socket server = new Socket(
            iPEndPoint.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp
            );

            server.Bind(iPEndPoint);
            server.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Server started Listening on port: 1234");

            var handler = await server.AcceptAsync();

            while (true)
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                SocketAsyncEventArgs args;

                //var received = await handler.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>, buffer);

                var received = await handler.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);   /*ERROR*/

                //convert bytes to string message
                var messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received);

                if (messageString != null)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Message from client: {0}", messageString);

                    var response = "Message Received!";

                    var responseByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

                    await handler.SendAsync(responseByte, SocketFlags.None);  /*ERROR*/
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
          
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }
}


Client.cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//Server code

//info about our localhost -- includes the ip address
public class HostInformationFetcherClient
{
    public async Task<IPHostEntry> GetHostEntryAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();

            IPHostEntry ipEntry = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(hostName);

            IPAddress ip = ipEntry.AddressList[0];

            //connects the server socket to client socket
            IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, 1234);
            Socket client = new Socket(
            iPEndPoint.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp
            );

            await client.ConnectAsync(iPEndPoint);

            while (true)
            {

                Console.Write("Send A Message:");
                var message = Console.ReadLine();

                //convert the string message to bytes message
                var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);


                //sends the message to the server
                await client.SendAsync(messageBytes, SocketFlags.None);  /*ERROR*/

                var buffer = new byte[1024];

                var received = await client.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);  /*ERROR*/
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
           
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }
}


I tried to find out what types of data are used for ReceiveAsync and SendAsync.

IMHO use the Memory<byte> overloads. You can't assume that one call to SendAsync and one call to ReceiveAsync on the other end will pass the entire message across. TCP can and will split and merge messages. This includes splitting multi-byte utf8 characters, causing UTF8.GetString to fail. It's your job to assemble whole messages together, perhaps by looking for delimiters like '\n' or sending the string length as a prefix.

Error in Server Code:
In the server code, you're encountering errors with ReceiveAsync and SendAsync methods. These methods expect a SocketAsyncEventArgs object as the first parameter, not a buffer directly. Here's how you can correct it:
// Change this line
// var received = await handler.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
// To this line
var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
args.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var received = await handler.ReceiveAsync(args);

And similarly for the SendAsync method:
// Change this line
// await handler.SendAsync(responseByte, SocketFlags.None);
// To this line
args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
args.SetBuffer(responseByte, 0, responseByte.Length);
await handler.SendAsync(args);

Similar changes are required in the the Client code too.
By passing the SocketAsyncEventArgs object properly configured with the buffer and other necessary parameters, you should be able to resolve the errors you're encountering. Make sure to apply these changes in both the server and client code

According to the docs, you seem to only be able to send and receive ArraySegment<byte> NOT byte[] via SendAsync() and ReceiveAsync(). Try turning the byte arrays into array segments:
using System.Text;
String toSend = "Upvote PLS?"; //set this to the data you want to send
byte[] oldByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toSend); 
ArraySegment<byte> arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(oldByteArray);
//Send your data here with arraySegment

And to turn it back to an array:
using System.Text;
ArraySegment<byte> arraySegment; 
//Give it a value via ReceiveAsync
byte[] newByteArray = arraySegment.ToArray();
string receiveValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newByteArray);
Console.WriteLine(receiveValue);

